# netbeans shows “Waiting For Connection (netbeans-xdebug)”

Tags: debugging, netbeans, xdebug

Can't seem to get netbeans to stop at my breakpoints.

When I run my debugger I get a never ending status of “Waiting For Connection (netbeans-xdebug)”.

in phpinfo I can see the following

```
> xdebug xdebug support enabled Version 2.6.0beta1 IDE Key  mysession
> Supported protocols   Revision DBGp - Common DeBuGger
> Protocol  $Revision: 1.145 $ Directive    Local Value Master Value
> xdebug.auto_trace Off Off xdebug.cli_color    0   0
> xdebug.collect_assignments    Off Off xdebug.collect_includes On  On
> xdebug.collect_params 0   0 xdebug.collect_return Off Off
> xdebug.collect_vars   Off Off xdebug.coverage_enable  On  On
> xdebug.default_enable On  On xdebug.dump.COOKIE   no value    no value
> xdebug.dump.ENV   no value    no value xdebug.dump.FILES  no value    no value
> xdebug.dump.GET   no value    no value xdebug.dump.POST   no value    no value
> xdebug.dump.REQUEST   no value    no value xdebug.dump.SERVER no value    no
> value xdebug.dump.SESSION no value    no value xdebug.dump_globals    On  On
> xdebug.dump_once  On  On xdebug.dump_undefined    Off Off
> xdebug.extended_info  On  On xdebug.file_link_format  no value    no value
> xdebug.filename_format    no value    no value
> xdebug.force_display_errors   Off Off xdebug.force_error_reporting    0   0
> xdebug.halt_level 0   0 xdebug.idekey netbeans-xdebug netbeans-xdebug
> xdebug.max_nesting_level  256 256 xdebug.max_stack_frames -1  -1
> xdebug.overload_var_dump  2   2 xdebug.profiler_aggregate Off Off
> xdebug.profiler_append    Off Off xdebug.profiler_enable  Off Off
> xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger    Off Off
> xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value  no value    no value
> xdebug.profiler_output_dir    C:\Windows\Temp C:\Windows\Temp
> xdebug.profiler_output_name   cachegrind.out.%p   cachegrind.out.%p
> xdebug.remote_addr_header no value    no value
> xdebug.remote_autostart   Off Off xdebug.remote_connect_back  Off Off
> xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time  3600    3600 xdebug.remote_enable   On  On
> xdebug.remote_handler dbgp    dbgp xdebug.remote_host 127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1
> xdebug.remote_log c:\xampp\php\logs\xdebug.log    c:\xampp\php\logs\xdebug.log
> xdebug.remote_mode    req req xdebug.remote_port  9000    9000
> xdebug.remote_timeout 200 200 xdebug.scream   Off Off
> xdebug.show_error_trace   Off Off xdebug.show_exception_trace Off Off
> xdebug.show_local_vars    Off Off xdebug.show_mem_delta   Off Off
> xdebug.trace_enable_trigger   Off Off
> xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value no value    no value
> xdebug.trace_format   0   0 xdebug.trace_options  0   0
> xdebug.trace_output_dir   C:\xampp\tmp    C:\xampp\tmp
> xdebug.trace_output_name  trace.%c    trace.%c
> xdebug.var_display_max_children   128 128
> xdebug.var_display_max_data   512 512 xdebug.var_display_max_depth    3   3
```

in my php.ini I have added the following

```
>  zend_extension = C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.6.0beta1-7.2-vc15.dll
> 
> xdebug.extended_info = on xdebug.remote_enable = 1
> xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
> xdebug.remote_port = 9000 xdebug.remote_autostart = 0
> xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0 xdebug.trace_output_dir =
> "C:\xampp\tmp" xdebug.remote_log = "c:\xampp\php\logs\xdebug.log"
> xdebug.idekey=netbeans-xdebug
```

project properties > Runconfiguration I have the following set

```
> Run As: Local Web Site 
> ProjectURL: http://localhost:9000/
```

In advended ...
I have Debugger Proxy: Host localhost Port: 9000

In Tools > Options > PHP > Debugging I have the following set

```
> Debugger Port: 9000
> Session ID: netbeans-xdebug
> Maximum Data Length : 2048
> Show Requested URLs is checked
```

Let me know if you need more information.

Addition: In netbeans I can see my requests coming into my network monitor. 
example:

```
Request URL: chrome-extension://cajoopobkbcpiniljegibngikdbidbkh/special.js
Method: GET
Status: 200 OK

Request Headers
Referer: http://localhost/register.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.108 Safari/537.36

Response Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
cache-control: no-cache
Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:; object-src 'self' blob: filesystem:;
Content-Type: application/javascript
ETag: "9otsANv03nd8a+7S0vdszi+cI6E="
```

My request in the browser hangs until I close process "Waiting for Connection (netbeans-xdebug)" and then loads normally.

More information thanks to the comment left by skomisa.

I run netstat -o -n -a | findstr 127.0.0.1:9000
and gotten the following. Showing that netbeans is not listening.

```
  TCP    127.0.0.1:9000         127.0.0.1:60365        ESTABLISHED     10700
  TCP    127.0.0.1:60365        127.0.0.1:9000         ESTABLISHED     10700
```

I have uninstalled mcafee and turned off windows defender.

Comment: See this article for about a dozen things you could check to resolve “Waiting For Connection (netbeans-xdebug)”: http://www.devside.net/wamp-server/netbeans-waiting-for-connection-netbeans-xdebug-issue

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of answers out there to solve this particular problem. I think you've not (re)searched about it. And you're doing some mistakes while debugging the code. In order to solve the problem follow these steps.

Your X-Debug configuration looks correct in `php.ini` file. But look at this slight modification I have for you.

```
zend_extension = C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.6.0beta1-7.2-vc15.dll
xdebug.extended_info = on
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_host = "localhost"  ; <-- "localhost" instead of 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_autostart = 0
;xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.remote_log = "c:\xampp\php\logs\xdebug.log"
xdebug.idekey=netbeans-xdebug
```

In run configuration you need to set your **Project URL** instead of `http://localhost:9000/`. That port number 9000 meant for XDebug purpose. So, change your run configuration to something like this,

```
http://localhost/<your_project_name>/index.php
```

Now note this,

1. If you use `xdebug.remote_host = "localhost"`, try with `http://localhost` else `http://127.0.0.1`.
2. If you have Apache port configured to some other port instead 80 you should append that port address along with `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.